# Application that receives DVB-H broadcast signal

Tags: dvb

DVB-H is a fairly new broadcasting medium. One purpose it is used for is to broadcast TV channels to TV phones and mobile decoders.

The software supplied by the service provider for windows does the job, but the display is small. I want to explore the possibilities of creating my own software that receives the signal and displays it to the screen. Also perhaps create an application to do the same on Blackberry and Android phones.

Anyone with any leads as to where I can get more info on coding with for DVB-H Broadcasts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are working with Linux, you can probably best use Linux API (see [this](http://www.linuxtv.org/docs/dvbapi/dvbapi.html)) under the [LinuxTV](http://www.linuxtv.org/projects.php) project.

Alternatively, in J2ME based platforms you can follow [JSR272](http://www.jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=272) to access the DVB-H receiver. See [this](http://www.blueboard.com/bluray/pdf/javaone_ts4693_v2.pdf) and this for more reference.

Unfortunately DVB-H based devices are specialized, so you need to specify which devices you want to support.